# Xcode 7.0.1 - SDKs not recognized > "iPhoneOSX.X (SDK not found)"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, base-sdk

I recently updated Xcode from 7.0 to 7.0.1 and now I'm unable to build with 8.0 as a base SDK. Typically this happens when upgrading and I simply needed to copy the SDKs into the right place.

As you can see, they are already there:

```
$ ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

iPhoneOS.sdk    iPhoneOS8.0.sdk iPhoneOS8.1.sdk iPhoneOS8.2.sdk iPhoneOS8.4.sdk iPhoneOS9.0.sdk
```

This is how the target looks:
[image]

My device (named Spock) now only has one entry where before there was an entry for every SDK:

[image]

I've tried:

- moving the files in and out.
- cleaning the build folder.
- restarting Xcode
- restarting my machine

Any other ways to get Xcode to recognize the SDKs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do installing multiple versions of Xcode and the 7.0.1 update installing in an unexpected place.

Here's what my Applications folder looked like before I fixed things:

Xcode -> Xcode 7.0
/Xcode6/Xcode -> Xcode 6.0.1
/Xcode6.4/Xcode -> Xcode 7.0.1

Notice how the 6.4 folder points to 7.0.1? Not good.

I must've had 2 versions of Xcode 7.0 installed. One I know I downloaded a dmg and the other I must have updated via the Mac App Store.

That means that when I went to look in the standard place:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs`

...I was looking at Xcode 7.0, *even though it was in the Applications folder and not a subfolder!*

In the end I reorganized my Applications folder like this:

Xcode -> Xcode 7.0.1
/Xcode6/Xcode -> Xcode 6.0.1
/Xcode7.0/Xcode -> Xcode 7.0

I also had to delete and re-add the 8.X SDKs but got it working again after that!

Answer (score 1):

What do you have under your xcodeproj, for your target, under the General tab and Deployment info?  Can you select another iOS version?

Similarly for your projet (instead of target)?
[image]

Comment: My deployment target is set to 8.0, but it is grayed out in the view you mentioned.